# Supported platforms

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On which platforms is ROS supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9081/supported-platforms/) by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2915 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-15**:
Please remember to accept answered questions.  Only the original poster can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean computer platforms, or hardware platforms? The only official computer platform that is supported right now is Ubuntu. (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation)

ROS can be used with numerous robot platforms, some of which are the PR2, iRobot Create, Lego NXT, Segway RMP, Arduino, Beagleboard, ArbotiX, Nao, and Qbo. You can see a complete list of all of the packages available here: http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php, there may be an existing package for your platform!

---

Originally posted by [RobotGrrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/41/robotgrrl/) with karma: 141 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our officially supported OS/software platforms are described in [REP 3: Target Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS Robots](http://ros.org/wiki/Robots) page is a good place to start if you're looking for robots using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4